# Deconstructing Array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have written a small script to email if there is not a "Yes" in a "Is Mailed" field of a row (Google Sheet).  It works fine, but I want to enhance the email with formatted text from the row of data.

I need help breaking this variable's data into multiple variables for use in the email.

```
var rangeSelect = auxSheet2.getRange(i, 1, 1, auxSheet2.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

The log output is correct and looks like this...

```
[17-11-04 12:49:38:534 PDT] [[Tue Oct 03 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2017, Captain, America, Engineering, 573-555-5555, me@mycompany.com, Equipment, Yes, We have two old 19" VGA monitors, , Test Submission 1, Yes]]
```

This is the code:

```
function moveAfter() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var auxSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Auxiliary");
    var lastColumn = auxSheet2.getLastColumn();

    for (var i = auxSheet2.getLastRow(); i > 1; i--) {

            var yesMailed = auxSheet2.getRange(i, 12).getValue();
            if (yesMailed != "Yes") {
                    var targetCell = auxSheet2.getRange(i, 12);
                    targetCell.setValue("Yes")

                    var rangeSelect = auxSheet2.getRange(i, 1, 1, auxSheet2.getLastColumn()).getValues();
                    Logger.log(rangeSelect)

                    var recipients = "me@work";
                    var message = 'This is a test ';
                    var subject = 'New item for the Auxiliary Annual Garage Sale';
                    var body = message + '  Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes';
                    MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
            }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) method returns a 2-dimensional array (row, column) of values.

Since you are pulling one row, you'll be interested in the first (and only) entry of the getValues array, and then depending on position a numbered index of that row.  For example:

```
var rangeRows = auxSheet2.getRange(i, 1, 1, auxSheet2.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var row = rangeRows[0];
// get a single element
var myEmail = row[5];
// make a string out of a couple of elements of row
var sometext = "My Fave Superhero is " + row[1] + " " + row[2];
// or join the whole row with commas
var joinedRecord = row.join(",");
```